# ASP.NET MVC4 to WCF DataServices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework, azure, wcf-data-services

I have a ASP .NET MVC4 application using Entity framework CodeFirst and I want to expose its data with WCF data services. I don't know where and how to begin.

Could you give me ways to follow ?

My final goal is to deploy this service on Windows Azure PaaS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Web Application project within your solution and add a new WCF DataServices item.

This WCF DataSercices should reference the same business layer as the one you might use within your `controllers`/`model builders` in your ASP .Net MVC4 application.

Then have a look [here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/101644) to learn about how to deploy on Azure.